# couldn't open "white_pawn.gif": no such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a chess game. So, I got the board down. But then, when I try to make a turtle in the shape of a white pawn, this happens:
(a bunch of error notes and then afterwards)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "white_pawn.gif": no such file or directory

it says tkinter error, but I'm using turtle. And my file "white_pawn.gif" is in the same folder as my python project. I don't know what is going on.

this is my code for the image:

```
image = "white_pawn.gif"
wn.register_shape(image)

w_pawn_1 = turtle.Turtle(shape=image)

wn.mainloop()
```

wn was "wn = turtle.Screen()" btw. Also, the other posts didn't work for me. I'm using windows 10 version 19045, python 3.10.5

Comment: Are you connected to your image directory when you run the program?  Or are you in some other directory?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: "it says tkinter error, but I'm using turtle" - yes, because turtle uses tkinter to create its graphics. "And my file "white_pawn.gif" is in the same folder as my python project." - this is **not what matters** for the purpose of finding the file. Please read the linked duplicate to understand how to place files / give paths in the script / run the script properly so that the path is properly understood. This system has to do with **how your computer works**, and is **completely independent of** both Tkinter and turtle.

Comment: @Person12343 I mean if you're using a relative path, as you are, then it should be relative to your current working directory.